# Persian text on carpet

Tags: translation, persian

I would be happy if someone could translate the text which is written on the carpet shown on the photo: [image: text on carpet with zodiac signs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jacobsenrugs.com/blog/is-your-rug-signed

This source gives an excellent and very interesting explanation for that sort of signature woven into oriental carpets.

Quote: "Most all signed rugs are city rugs, rugs woven in a metropolitan area where someone can be found to write the initials or inscription even if the weaver is illiterate. Almost never is the signature the actual mark of the weaver; rather, it is almost always the mark of the entrepreneur or money man who caused the rug to be woven. Usually the inscription is in Arabic, or in Farsi (Persian) written in Arabic script."

Also: "Not all text appearing in a cartouche in rug is a signature; some of what looks like text is not really writing at all. There is a long history of city weavers incorporating decorative Arabic calligraphy into their rug designs. Often this script is so ornamental that it is no longer readable as text. This kind of stylized writing used as design is often called "Kufic" or "Kufesque." "

Wikipedia says about "Kufic": Kufic is the oldest calligraphic form of the various Arabic scripts and consists of a modified form of the old Nabataean script. Kufic developed around the end of the 7th century in Kufa, Iraq, from which it takes its name, and other centres.

Comment: Just for information: the style of script here is not Kufic: it is Naskh.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. I didn't really think it was Kufic, since it should be almost purely ornamental in that case. But I'd never heard of Naskh, so you have enlightened me. In fact, I've found this whole experience very educational, lol.

Answer (score 0):

It is Persian, not Arabic, but a bit too faint for my old eyes.

Comment: شکارش نباشد جز از شیر و گور  ازیراش خوانند بهرام گور

it says he is very good hunter of lions and goor (some thing like bofalo) and that is why they call him "Bahram goor" 

------------ it means he is a power ful man in old ages

Comment: this is the poem :

https://fa.wikisource.org/wiki/%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%87%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%87/%D9%BE%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%87%DB%8C_%D8%A8%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%85_%DA%AF%D9%88%D8%B1

Comment: I am Persian by the way